# How to use weather api in c#

Tags: c#, coordinates, weather-api

I want to implement weather information which will show me results that depends on my longitude and latitude.

My app is getting coordinates from GPS so getting them is not a problem. Only thing is, I want to show some weather information for the city that is nearest me and that it has weather info.

Can you give me some ideas and solutions.

What do you think about google weather API?

How to make this to search for the nearest and how to give to this code lat and long.

```
public static void GoogleWeather(string location)  
    {  
        HttpWebRequest GoogleRequest;  
        HttpWebResponse GoogleResponse = null;  
        XmlDocument GoogleXMLdoc = null;  
        try  
        {  
            GoogleRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=" + string.Format(location));  
            GoogleResponse = (HttpWebResponse)GoogleRequest.GetResponse();  
            GoogleXMLdoc = new XmlDocument();  
            GoogleXMLdoc.Load(GoogleResponse.GetResponseStream());  

            XmlNode root = GoogleXMLdoc.DocumentElement;  

            XmlNodeList nodeList1 = root.SelectNodes("weather/forecast_information");  
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<b>City : " + nodeList1.Item(0).SelectSingleNode("city").Attributes["data"].InnerText + "</b>");  

            XmlNodeList nodeList = root.SelectNodes("weather/current_conditions");  
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(" 
");  
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(" 
<table class="bordered" cellpadding="5"> 
<tbody><tr><td><b><big><nobr>" + nodeList.Item(0).SelectSingleNode("temp_c").Attributes["data"].InnerText + " °C | " + nodeList.Item(0).SelectSingleNode("temp_f").Attributes["data"].InnerText + " °F</nobr></big></b>");  
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<b>Current:</b> " + nodeList.Item(0).SelectSingleNode("condition").Attributes["data"].InnerText + "");  
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("" + nodeList.Item(0).SelectSingleNode("wind_condition").Attributes["data"].InnerText + "");  
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(nodeList.Item(0).SelectSingleNode("humidity").Attributes["data"].InnerText);  
            nodeList = root.SelectNodes("descendant::weather/forecast_conditions");  
            foreach (XmlNode nod in nodeList)  
            {  
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</td> 
<td align="center">" + nod.SelectSingleNode("day_of_week").Attributes["data"].InnerText+ "");  
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<img src="http://www.google.com" + nod.SelectSingleNode("icon").Attributes["data"].InnerText + "" alt="" + nod.SelectSingleNode("condition").Attributes["data"].InnerText + "">");  
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(nod.SelectSingleNode("low").Attributes["data"].InnerText + "°F | ");  
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(nod.SelectSingleNode("high").Attributes["data"].InnerText + "°F");  
            }  
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</td> 
</tr> 
</tbody></table> 

");  
        }  
        catch (System.Exception ex)  
        {  
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ex.Message);  
        }  
        finally  
        {  
            GoogleResponse.Close();  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: What we think of the Google Weather API is immaterial.  What are you doing and in what way doesn't it work?

Comment: People sure can be quick to downvote. Let's hope that since you have added some code, they will change their selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually had a similar issue a while back.

I decided to go with Wunderground as I had too many issues with Google Weather. *Edit, I added a working google example below the wunderground one. The google api requires a city name or a zip code it seems.

Here is my example, pardon my sloppy code, typing this from memory.

```
public static DayOfWeek Wunderground(string latlong)
    {
        //Insert your API key in the below URL
        //string latlong = "37.8,-122.4";
        string url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/*insertyourapikeyhere*/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/"+latlong+".xml";

        HttpWebRequest web = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        web.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        web.PreAuthenticate = true;
        web.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19";
        web.GetResponse();
        //Get Dopplar Image
        var dop = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/7dca468f5dd2ff1b/animatedradar/q/TX/Houston.gif?newmaps=1&timelabel=1&width=640&height=480&timelabel.y=10&num=15&delay=50";
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadFile(dop, "dop.gif");

        //Prepare my custom property
        var d = new WeatherLib.DayOfWeek();
        d.Current = new WDay();
        WDay forecast = new WDay();
        var conditions = d;
        var xmlConditions = new XmlDocument();

        //download the api xml
        XDocument api = XDocument.Load(url);
        api.Save("api.xml");
        xmlConditions.Load(string.Format(@"api.xml"));

        XmlNodeList list = xmlConditions.SelectNodes("/response/current_observation");
        WDay current = d.Current;

        //Parse out the XML data
        foreach (XmlNode node in list)
        {
            current.WeatherText = node.SelectSingleNode("weather").InnerText;
            current.TempCurrentF = node.SelectSingleNode("temp_f").InnerText;
            current.TempCurrentC = node.SelectSingleNode("temp_c").InnerText;
            current.Humidity = node.SelectSingleNode("relative_humidity").InnerText;
            current.WindDirection = node.SelectSingleNode("wind_dir").InnerText;
            current.WindSpeedM = node.SelectSingleNode("wind_mph").InnerText;
            current.WindSpeedK = node.SelectSingleNode("wind_kph").InnerText;
            current.Barometer = node.SelectSingleNode("pressure_mb").InnerText;
            current.HeatIndexF = node.SelectSingleNode("heat_index_f").InnerText;
            current.HeatIndexC = node.SelectSingleNode("heat_index_c").InnerText;
            current.WindChill = node.SelectSingleNode("windchill_string").InnerText;
            current.UVIndex = node.SelectSingleNode("UV").InnerText;
            current.RainAmount = node.SelectSingleNode("precip_today_in").InnerText;
            current.Visibility = node.SelectSingleNode("visibility_mi").InnerText;
            current.DewPoint = node.SelectSingleNode("dewpoint_f").InnerText;


        }return d;
    }
```

Google example

```
public static DayOfWeek Google(string zip)
    {
        string urlstring = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather="+zip;
        var d = new WeatherLib.DayOfWeek();
        d.Monday = new WDay();
        d.Tuesday = new WDay();
        d.Wednesday = new WDay();
        d.Thursday = new WDay();
        d.Friday = new WDay();
        d.Saturday = new WDay();
        d.Sunday = new WDay();
        d.Current = new WDay();

        WDay forecast = new WDay();
        var conditions = d;
        var xmlConditions = new XmlDocument();
        XDocument api = XDocument.Load(urlstring);
        api.Save("api.xml");
        xmlConditions.Load(string.Format(@"api.xml"));
        if (xmlConditions.SelectSingleNode("xml_api_reply/weather/problem_cause") != null)
        {
            conditions = null;
        }
        else
        {

            var singleNode = xmlConditions.SelectSingleNode("xml_api_reply/weather/current_conditions/condition");
            if (singleNode != null)
                if (singleNode.Attributes != null)
                    conditions.Current.WeatherText =
                        singleNode.Attributes[
                            "data"].InnerText;
            var node = xmlConditions.SelectSingleNode("xml_api_reply/weather/current_conditions/temp_c");
            if (node != null)
                if (node.Attributes != null)
                    conditions.Current.TempCurrentC =
                        node.Attributes["data"]
                            .InnerText;
            var selectSingleNode1 = xmlConditions.SelectSingleNode("xml_api_reply/weather/current_conditions/temp_f");
            if (selectSingleNode1 != null)
                if (selectSingleNode1.Attributes != null)
                    conditions.Current.TempCurrentF =
                        selectSingleNode1.Attributes["data"]
                            .InnerText;
            var singleNode1 = xmlConditions.SelectSingleNode("xml_api_reply/weather/current_conditions/humidity");
            if (singleNode1 != null)
                if (singleNode1.Attributes != null)
                    conditions.Current.Humidity =
                        singleNode1.Attributes[
                            "data"].InnerText;
            var xmlNode1 = xmlConditions.SelectSingleNode("xml_api_reply/weather/current_conditions/wind_condition");
            if (xmlNode1 != null)
                if (xmlNode1.Attributes != null)
                    conditions.Current.WindSpeedM =
                        xmlNode1.Attributes
                            ["data"].InnerText;

            if (xmlConditions.SelectSingleNode("xml_api_reply/weather/problem_cause") != null)
            {
                conditions = null;
            }
            else
            {
                XmlNodeList list = xmlConditions.SelectNodes("/xml_api_reply/weather");
                foreach(XmlNode node1 in list)
                {
                    XmlNodeList days = node1.SelectNodes("forecast_conditions");
                    foreach (XmlNode doo in days)
                    {
                        string dow = doo.SelectSingleNode("day_of_week").Attributes["data"].InnerText;
                        switch (dow)
                        {
                            case "Mon":
                                forecast = d.Monday;
                                break;
                            case "Tue":
                                forecast = d.Tuesday;
                                break;
                            case "Wed":
                                forecast = d.Wednesday;
                                break;
                            case "Thu":
                                forecast = d.Thursday;
                                break;
                            case "Fri":
                                forecast = d.Friday;
                                break;
                            case "Sat":
                                forecast = d.Saturday;
                                break;
                            case "Sun":
                                forecast = d.Sunday;
                                break;
                        }
                        forecast.WeatherText = doo.SelectSingleNode("condition").Attributes["data"].InnerText;
                        forecast.TempHiF = doo.SelectSingleNode("high").Attributes["data"].InnerText;                         
                    }
                }       
            }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for that code. I will look at it. One question. I see that you are receiving zip code inside the function. I was thinking to receive long and lat as I will be using thiswhile driving and when I press get weather buttonit willnsen long and lat an give me nearest town that has weather informations. That is exactly what I would like to do. But I will look at Wunderground.

Comment: you could use google maps to find the city near that lat long, for example the lat long I posted above. http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=37.8,-122.4&sensor=false

Then parse the xml for the zip or city name then pass to that script.

Comment: Okay thank you! But the script you have posted accepts zip code too:)

Comment: Wunderground will take Zip, City Name, or LatLong. Google will only take zip or city name.

Comment: Is there anyway to contact you by email?