# Is it possible to download certain information of a webpage and implement it into a Web Service?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

Basically in short Im doing a school website project (Aspx.NET) and inside Im being forced to use a Web Service of my own.
My sub page has all the information about a certain Match for a certain football team and i need to add the current weather in the city (Madrid) and i cant seem to figure out how.

Im trying to download the content of a google page and pickout the weather part of the page 
https://www.google.com/search?q=weather+in+spain&oq=weather+in+&aqs=chrome.2.69i59l3j69i57j0l2.6653j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

any idea on how to do this?

Comment: You can use weather api - https://code.google.com/archive/p/python-weather-api/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use weather api in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725812/how-to-use-weather-api-in-c-sharp)